# How to run this PowerShell command with Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, command, invoke, remote-server

I want to run the following PowerShell command on remote site

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
```

and

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\memory\available mbytes" -MaxSamples 10 -SampleInterval 1
```

Is that the invoke command format like this?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 {
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem, this looks valid

Answer (score 0):

If winRM is set up on the target, you can pass the ComputerName parameter in Get-CimInstance right from the start:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName server01| select csname, lastbootuptime
```

Same with Get-Counter:

```
Get-Counter -ComputerName server01 -Counter "\memory\available mbytes" -MaxSamples 10 -SampleInterval 1
```